# /usr/bin/C++ not compile as gcc with Shared library

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I try to work on shared library.

In detail, I following this link:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html.

Everything ok with this command:

```
$ gcc -L/home/user/foo -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
$ ./test
```

But when i change from gcc to /usr/bin/c++, ANd change commands to:

```
$ /usr/bin/c++ -L/home/user/foo -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/foo -Wall -o test2 main.c -lfoo
/tmp/ccpEHbNV.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It can't find the method foo in my libfoo.so.

I also try by another way with -rdynamic, It also work well with gcc:

```
gcc -rdynamic ./libfoo.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/foo -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

But It also have the same error with /usr/bin/c++.

Please show me how to make it work with /usr/bin/c++.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Do you have any other c++ compile than g++ installed?

Comment: Don't mix and match compilers, the name mangling won't match. Compile both the lib and `main.c` with either `gcc`, or `g++`, not both. You could also wrap the declarations with `extern "C"` and appropriate compiler guards if you really do need to use the lib in both C and C++.

Comment: `/usr/bin/c++` is a standard name for C++ compiler. It can be any compiler on your system. For example, on my system it is the same as `g++`. You can check it with `ls -l /usr/bin/{g,c}++`. On some systems `c++` is a symlink to `g++`. On my system it is just a copy of g++ (checked with `md5sum /usr/bin/{g,c}++`). So it is impossible to answer unless you tell us which compiler is disguised under `/usr/bin/c++`. By the way, the commands work with `g++`, so it is unlikely that your `c++` is `g++`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you compile the library with a C compiler and your code with a C++ compiler, you need to ensure that the library's functions are declared with C linkage in C++.

Comment: I don't understand. /usr/bin/c++ is compiler in C++ right. If I change anything from C to Cpp. I also meet with the same problem.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Here is the link of my C++: 
/usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++.

So please help me compile this shared library by /usr/bin/c++

Comment: @JameLenon, once again: `cd /etc/alternatives; ls -l c++`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: c++ -> /usr/bin/g++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, this is because different symbol naming between C and C++ compiled libraries, As C++ have overloaded functions the naming for each symbol should include type of arguments in symbol name or something which identifies the actual function or class method based on its arguments.
Unlike C++, C doesn't have this issue, because of no function overloading and its standard ABI. if you want mix C/C++ files you have to compile all the C & C++ codes with g++ and also add extern C keyword to definition of C codes

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// your C definitions (only function definitions) goes here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming probably because of name mangling of C++. /usr/bin/c++ ends up as /usr/bin/g++. gcc is a C compiler while g++ is a C++ compiler. You need to compile your library libfoo.so with g++ and then try to link. It should work.

Comment: _"gcc is a C compiler while g++ is a C++ compiler"_ - GCC is C _and_ C++ compiler. Read _NAME_ section from the man page.

Comment: I know gcc means GNU Compiler Collection. Historically, gcc is the command for C language.

Answer (score -1):

What is the version of gcc and c++ you are using ?

Ideally within the *same* compiler tool-chain family there should be no error.

In fact, i wrote the code, compiled and executed the same example without any issues.

Please note the version of gcc/c++ i am using.

```
gcc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
g++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
```

i wrote a shell script file to execute the commands

```
strace c++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
strace c++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
strace c++ -L. -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo
```

and collected the strace output of the compilation and linking. Please see the link below
http://pastebin.com/nJpQuCfS

Hope this helps.